# Add title to my series line [mschart]

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I am using `Chart control` to display my network statistics (download, upload):

```
chart1.Titles.Add("Test Chart");

Series seriesDownload = new Series("KB/s");
seriesDownload.Color = Color.DarkBlue;
seriesDownload.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
seriesDownload.BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series.Add(seriesDownload);

Series seriesPps = new Series("pps");
seriesPps.Color = Color.Black;
seriesPps.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
seriesPps.BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series.Add(seriesPps);
```

Is it possible to add text near each line in order to distinguish between both colors ?

[image]

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series[1].LegendText = chart1.Series[1].Name = str + " KB/s";
    DataPoint Point = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
    Point.Label = chart1.Series[1].Name;

    DataPoint _point = default(DataPoint);
    foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[1].Points)
    {
       item.Label = "";
       item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will add a label with the series name to the last point on your series. This is `VB.NET` but you should be able to parse it to `C#`

```
'remove all previous datapoint labels
Dim _point As DataPoint
For Each _point In Chart1.Series(i).Points
    _point.Label = ""
    _point.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None
Next


'add label to last point
Dim Point As DataPoint = Chart1.Series(i).Points(Chart1.Series(i).Points.Count - 1)
Point.Label = Chart1.Series(i).Name
Point.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
```

[image]

Or are you looking to populate the legend with the series name?? then

```
Chart1.Series(i).LegendText = Chart1.Series(i).Name
```

**EDIT**  ***based on the askee submitted code in `C#`***

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[1].Points)
    {
        item.Label = "";
    }

    chart1.Series[1].LegendText = chart1.Series[1].Name = str + " KB/s";
    DataPoint Point = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
    Point.Label = chart1.Series[1].Name;

}
```

Comment: I am looking for display the title "KB/s" near the blue line so i have try chart1.Series[0].LegendText = chart1.Series[0].Name = "KB/s" but nothing changed

Comment: does your `Chart` have a legend? Make sure its enabled. Otherwise you have to add a new legend to the chart such as `Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend1")` and then set legend text. Also make sure you are using the correct `Series[i]` so that you are indexing the correct series

Comment: legend enable property is set to true and after set my legend title i can see this text but above my first line

Comment: you wont be able to align the legend without changing `innerplotpositions` etc . it would be much easier to add a label to end of each series, like I did in the first solution i showed you

Comment: Ok now after you added the pic i can see and this is what i want but i didn't succeed to move this code into c#

Comment: using http://converter.telerik.com/ i get this 
`DataPoint Point = Chart1.Series(i).Points(Chart1.Series(i).Points.Count - 1);

Point.Label = Chart1.Series(i).Name;`

Comment: Ok i put it inside my timer tick and it work but the string "KB/s" exist for every point inside my chart, how can i ensure the only one will display like in your example ?

Comment: ok see my edited code. I guess you are looping through and it adds a label at each point. The new code now erases all labels and then adds a label to the last point

Comment: Please see my update, it crash because _point = null and i don't understand why

Comment: I edited your code. see does this work. Changed _point to item and you want this label deletion to happen before you try and add the last label. So switched the order of the code

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of the series is not good practice, as the `SeriesCollection` can be indexed by name (e.g., `chart1.Series["MySeries"]`) which might then fail after the name change.

If you're trying to add a static label at the end of the code, you can do it as a smart label. Look into the `"#VALX#", "#VAL#"` modifiers to use in labels:

```
DataPoint Point = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
Point.Label = "#VAL" + " kB/s";
```

which will automatically add the current x or y value to the label. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687(v=vs.110).aspx

As an aside, it's very helpful to put the names of your `Series` into const variables in the class (or static variables in another class), so you can index them without fear of typos. Makes your code much easier to understand, too.

```
private const string _downloadSeries = "download";

// in some initialization method
Series seriesDownload = new Series(_downloadSeries);
chart1.Series.Add(seriesDownload);

// Access the series
DataPoint point = chart1.Series[_downloadSeries].Points[0];
```

for example.

EDIT: If you just want to distinguish the two colors, that's exactly what a legend is for. If you want to show the latest value as well, then this code will do that